# How to search and replace all occurrences of a string in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am doing translations on android studio and now I need to replace some strings that I had wrongly translated. When I search using CTRL+SHIFT+F I indeed get all occurrences but when I use the replace shortcut CTRL+SHIFT+R and try to replace I get a quick popup saying `Occurrences in project configuration files are skipped` then there is a button which says `Include them`. When I click that button, the find window opens then nothing happens. How do I search and replace from the ENTIRE project including the configuration files?

Comment: Make sure that the inProject tab is selected.

Comment: do you want to change the variable name or variable value?

Comment: @MukulBhardwaj I want to change variable values, not names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select string and use     **Alt+Shift+R** as Eclipse shortcut and **Refactor** your string, like below screenshots.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There really is no point in editing config files (because all of them are generated by Android Studio) so just don't click the button on the popup you described.

If I am mistaken then tell me what kind of config files you might want to edit.

Comment: This is true, most of the files are generated by android studio but even strings in .xml files and .json files are bundled under these config files. Also I have git submodules in this project and they too are under 'config' files

Comment: @Alfy Won't they just be regenerated on the next build?

Comment: Also, running my own find and replace it does change string.xml and any of my .json files.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting, let me try Invalidate Cache and try again

Comment: @Alfy are these config files regenerated every build?

Answer (score -1):

Edit -> Find -> Replace in path 
and then In Project

Answer (score -1):

In Android Studio:

> Edit -> Find -> Replace in path

Comment: @Alfy can you explain why you gave negative vote. You didn't mention that you have done that.